# JScrollpane scrollbar resizing issue

Tags: java, resize, jscrollpane

I have the following problem:

I have JScrollPane containing an image.

The scrollpane is inside a JPanel together with other components in order to be able to layout the whole thing with a BorderLayout (the scrollpane is the CENTER and I have something in the SOUTH).

This JPanel is in a JSplitPane.

The JSplitPane is finally inside a JFrame.

```
JFrame
{
 JSplitpane
 {
  JPanel(BorderLayout)
  {
   JScrollPane(CENTER)
   {
    BufferedImage
   }

   JPanel(SOUTH)
   {...}
  }
 }
}
```

My problem now is that when I resize my frame the image in the scrollPane resizes fine until it reaches the images size. Then the image is stretched which I want to prevent.
I tried wrapping the JScrollPane in a JPanel that is layout with a FlowLayout. That works fine for the resizing bit but the scrollbars disappear once I resize the frame.

I overrode the scrollPane's setSize() method and found out that the size of the scrollpane is always set to the image's size once the frame is resized. I don't have a clue how to fix that though.

Every hint is appreciated.

Cheers,

Ben

Comment: my apologies for the weird Component scheme. Looked better in the preview...

Comment: how do you add the image in to the scrollpane...

Comment: I subclassed the scrollpane class and during initialization I load a BufferedImage which I add to the viewport by calling setViewportView()

Comment: Saw your update (btw, you should add comments to the responses rather than adding a new response), and at this point I suggest writing a SSCEP (small, self-contained example program) that just creates the main frame/scrollpane/buffered image, and update your question with this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should be good if you call `setMaximumSize()` on the `JScrollPane` with the width/height of the `BufferedImage` (but haven't tried it).

And as a general comment: it's a bad idea to override Swing components just to add children. Instead, create a controller class that creates and composes base components.

---

I reread your question, and am wondering: is the problem that the image gets stretched, or that the scrollbars are disappearing? If you want to keep the scrollbars on the screen even when there's nothing to scroll, take a look at the `setVerticalScrollBarPolicy()` and `setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy()` methods.

Comment: Sorry for using the answer button. I'm new to this and most of the time stuff makes sense AFTER you pushed a button...
Anyways, I solved my problem and it appeared to me when I wrote the SSCEP. I messed around with the maximumSize and the preferredSize and somehow managed to set the maximumSize always to the preferred size right after initalization which caused the weird behaviour.

I'm a little bit wiser now, I guess...
Thanks for your help.

-Ben